# Disable submit button until field is validated on database

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am using AJAX to validate a code entered into a form field and if it's valid, a message is displayed saying it's valid, otherwise they get a message that it is invalid. No issues with this part. The next thing that I want to do is disable the submit button until the code is valid, otherwise user can enter whatever they want and still go to download page. My script is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#orgname").change(function() { 

var usr = $("#orgname").val();

if(usr.length >= 2)
{
$("#status").html('<img align="absmiddle" src="images/loader.gif" /> Checking Code...');

$.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
url: "checkcode.cfm", 
data: "orgname="+ usr, 
success: function(msg){ 

$("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){ 

if(msg == 'OK')
{ 
$("#orgname").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
$("#orgname").addClass("object_ok");
 document.getElementById("formsubmit").removeAttribute("disabled");
$(this).html(' <img align="absmiddle" src="images/accepted.png" /> ');
} 
else 
{ 
$("#orgname").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
$("#orgname").addClass("object_error");
$(this).html(msg);
document.getElementById("formsubmit").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

}});}});}
else
{
$("#status").html('The Code should have at least 2 characters.');
$("#orgname").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
$("#orgname").addClass("object_error");
}});});
```

I am new to AJAX as well. As you can see I am putting the enable and disable script in the correct places, but it's not working. If I use a style or disable attribute on the button, it stays disabled. Likewise if I disable the button using JS when this page loads, it stays disabled the entire time.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the `}});}});}` is correctly closing all blocks/etc and not causing a syntax error, resulting in the JS not executing?

Answer (score 3):

Use `$('#formsubmit').prop('disabled',true);` and `$('#formsubmit').prop('disabled',false);` to disable and enable the button, respectively. jQuery will handle all the browser differences.

Comment: Peter, Yes, there are no syntax errors. Alan, I tried that and it is not working. The button stays enabled all the time. I am assuming that I just replace the two document.getelementbyID lines with yours. I did that. Do I need to put some sort of condition disable at the top? I did try setting disabled = "disabled" on the button control but that keeps it disabled all the time. Am I supposed to call a function on the button control maybe?

Comment: @Bruce, If everything but the enabling and disabling of the submit button works as expected, are you sure the ID of the submit button is "formsubmit"?  That's all I can think of.

Comment: One thing, it will probably work if you remove the extra function within the `success: function(msg)` function, as it will automatically be triggered when the request completes.  Adding another function within it may prevent it from executing the code within the inside function.